What is the fully expanded version of "than be/do ..."?
What is the fully expanded version of the part after "than" in

than be ....
than do ...

? For example:

There are more people today than are expected.
The swimming pool is more luxurious than is necessary.

Is the following correct?

The swimming pool is more luxurious than it is necessary.


It depends on what the first part of the sentence is! "The swimming pool is more luxurious than it is necessary for a swimming pool to be" (or "for that particular pool to be"). Your first sentence doesn't make sense, but "There are more people here today than were expected" would mean "More people have come to the event than we expected when we planned it".

I would understand it to be "than [luxuriousness] is necessary".

Note that once you've set this up, you can delete the final verb (but don't have to): "... more people today than expected," "more luxurious than necessary." At least, as long as it doesn't create confusion. Your final example is probably not what was meant—that the swimming pool is very luxurious and is not very necessary—but one might accidentally give that impression by deleting "is." (The intended meaning is "the swimming pool is more luxurious than [the level of luxury that] is necessary."
